# Magento2 Installtion errors on windows through composer

Tags: magento2, composer

I am facing a problem while making a installation of magento2 by composer i got the following error after a consecutive successful downloading of some modules. Can one please help me to sort out this.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has limit on max path length: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx#maxpath

You can use VirtualBox/Vagrant with Linux, that do not have this issue